# nhibernate second level cache with collections

Tags: nhibernate, caching

I have a class which has a collection, `Category.ChildCategoryLinks`

I have set this as cached, using a Read-Write cache policy.  However, whenever a new `ChildCategoryLink` is added that references the same Category, the cache is not updated, and thus it is resulting in stale data.

I am using Fluent NHibernate to configure NH.  I am not specifying any cache regions.  Any idea why the cache is not being flushed / updated, once the new ChildLink is created?

Comment: Could you supply the relevant fluent maps and a small code sample?

Comment: I will supply them early next week as i dont have direct access to the code right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate will not invalidate the cache unless you update the collection in code too; changing the inverse side (the many-to-one) is not enough.

Also, make sure you do everything inside a transaction.

Comment: This is a multiple parent-child relationship. If i add a parent, i add a link to the .Parents collection, which is the inverse=false of the relationship. If i had to add it as well to the Parent.Children collection, it has to fetch ALL the children when i access it, which is not ideal.

Comment: @KarlCassar: if the collection is cached, that shouldn't be an issue :-)

Comment: But the collection is not being updated automatically for some reason! If I restart the application, hence cache is reset, then it will appear.